# Способ реализации индексации элементов в блоке

Tags: javascript, html

Предположим есть блок #container и в нем множество типовых элементов, например кнопок.

```
<div id="container">
    <input type="button" value="тыц">
    <input type="button" value="тыц" id='thisOne'>
    <input type="button" value="тыц">
    <input type="button" value="тыц">
    <input type="button" value="тыц">
    <input type="button" value="тыц">
    <input type="button" value="тыц">
    <input type="button" value="тыц">
</div>
```

Элементы динамически добавляются (в конец стека) и удаляются (из конца стека), и их нужно индексировать. Я так понимаю, что это можно делать 2мя способами:

1. Добавлять свойство data-index при создании кнопки:

   ```
   let butt = document.createElement('input');
   butt.type =  "button";
   butt.id = "thisOne"
   butt.dataset.index = "1";
   ```

(data- атрибуты, кстати, только поддерживают строковые значения, так что индекс придется переводить в число)

либо

2. Создать функцию которая возвращает коллекцию кнопок и искать среди них искомую.

   ```
   function fetchButtons()  {
       let result = container.querySelectorAll('input[type=button]');
       return result;
   }


   var collection = fetchButtons();
   var index;
   for (i=0; i<collection.length; i++ )  {
       thatOne = collection[i];
       if (thatOne == thisOne)  {
           index = i;
           console.log(index);
       }
   }
   ```

Я делаю небольшой проект начинающего уровня, могу реализовать и так и так, но хотелось бы узнать - как сделать правильнее с точки зрения стандартов, совместимости, быстродействия оптимизации и т.д.?

Comment: Зачем индексировать?

Comment: @MishaSaidov Помимо контейнера с элементами управления есть еще один контейнер с текстовыми элементами, каждый из них соответствует кнопке. Индексировать для того, чтобы, условно говоря, при нажатии на кнопку под индексом 5 менялся текст под индексом 5 где-то в другом месте.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Есть еще такой вариант. С ним вам вообще не придется что-то индексировать при условии, что среди детей родителя не будет лишних элементов. А так, вариант с атрибутом `data-index` тоже не плох. В нем нет лишних циклов, что хорошо скажется на производительности при большом количестве кнопок. В крупных проектах в основном используются фреймворки, которые в принципе не приводят к подобным дилеммам.

```js
document.querySelectorAll("#container > input[type='button']").forEach(item => {
  item.addEventListener("click", e => {
    let element = e.currentTarget;

    Array.from(element.parentElement.children).forEach((child, index) => {
      if (child === element) {
        console.log("Вы нажали на элемент с индексом " + index);
      }
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <input type="button" value="тыц">
  <input type="button" value="тыц" id='thisOne'>
  <input type="button" value="тыц">
  <input type="button" value="тыц">
  <input type="button" value="тыц">
  <input type="button" value="тыц">
  <input type="button" value="тыц">
  <input type="button" value="тыц">
</div>
```

Comment: Извините, я правильно понял, что предложенный Вами вариант это в принципе то что я написал в примере № 2, т.е. создать массив/коллекцию элементов и перебирать их, сравнивая с образцом, а потом номер итерации записать в индекс, верно?

Comment: @IgorCheglakov, да, я потом только заметил. Затупил)

Comment: Ничегострашного, Ваш синтаксис и реализация мне будут полезны, спасибо.